# Ember.js Handlebars block helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Apparently this does not work: http://jsbin.com/efapob/3/edit

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('foo', function(options) {
  var result = 'BEFORE '
           + options.fn(this)
           + ' AFTER';
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

And I assume it's because the fn() writes directly to the output buffer.

However, I need a way to directly work with the output of the block's content.

I tried overwriting a view's `render` function, but that also didn't lead me anywhere.

(Background: I'm trying to write an `{{#ifchanged}}` helper block that only renders if the contents have changed in comparison to the last call. The use case is a loop that should display something every time one property of the model is different to the last one. If you have other ideas how to achieve this, comments very appreciated!)

Comment: Are you using ember-data?

Comment: Yes. Interesting, how could this be connected?

Comment: Because you can use the isDirty property, to know when some property changes. Give a look in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, in this specific use-case I worked around the issue of not being able to use the return of `fn()` like so:

```js
var ifchanged_last;
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifchanged', function(property, options) {
  var value = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, property);
  if (value !== ifchanged_last) {
    options.fn(this, options);
  }
  ifchanged_last = value;
  return;
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each content}}
  {{#ifchanged some_key}}
    The value changed
  {{/ifchanged}}
{{/each}}
```

Large room for improvement, but a usable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isDirty` property from `DS.Model` to know when the data changes.

In some template:

```
{{#if isDirty}}
    You changed the model<br/>
{{/if}}
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/f66CA/) with the demo.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to know *if the model has changed*, but just if one property is different to the last one inside of an {{each}} loop.

Comment: you have a array of elements then in the iteration, if some property of current element is different from the previous, do you want to know?

Comment: Precisely that. I have an array of items that have a 'group' property, and for every group I want to display a line of text, but just once.